# magento 2 theme suddenly stopped working

Tags: magento2, theme

Created a custom magento 2 theme and started working with it. It was working fine.
Suddenly, one day the theme is not working in frontend. In admin panel i can see the theme name, but in frontend it is showing default magento theme which is my parent theme. 
I had removed the theme and re-installed. But, still not working.

The same theme, in local development is working and also on another magento setup. I think, there is some database problem.

Can anybody help me out on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the theme table... `update theme set type=1 where theme_id=`

Answer (score 2):

Please check all files are there if any files missing or not complete as in the main theme then replace that files or simply installing the theme once again if this is done properly then follow all these steps using CMD :

1. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
2. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
3. `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
4. Delete folders except `.htaccess` file from, `<m2_root_directory>/pub/static` and then `<m2_root_directory>/var/view_preprocessed`.
5. Flush Magento cache by typing **`php bin/magento cache:flush`** on command line.

Then recheck it once.I hope it will work

Comment: the problem was in the theme table... `update theme set type=1 where theme_id=`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to flush/clean cache, compile content once again.

Comment: the problem was in the theme table... `update theme set type=1 where theme_id=`